# Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, http, alamofire

I'm very new to Swift 3, and I have to do a GET request on my API. I'm using Alamofire, which uses Asynchronous functions.

I do exactly the same on my Android App, and the GET returns JSON data

This is my code in swift:

```
    func getValueJSON() -> JSON {
        var res = JSON({})
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        myGroup.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url_).responseJSON { response in
            res = response.result.value as! JSON
            print("first result", res)
            myGroup.leave()
        }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Finished all requests.", res)
        }
        print("second result", res)
        return res
   }
```

But I have a problem with the line "res = response.result.value" which gives me the error:

> Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT

I really don't understand where the problem comes from, it was pretty hard to do a "synchronous" function, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

My objective is to store the result of the request in a variable that I return. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use Alamofire together with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) because that way you'll be able to parse JSON easier a lot.

Here's a classical example:

```
Alamofire.request("http://example.net", method: .get).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If you need to pass `parameters`, or `headers`, just add it in the `request` method.

```
 let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type:": "application/json"
 ]

 let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "key": "value"
 ]
```

So your request will be something like this (this is POST request):

```
Alamofire.request("http://example.net", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

switch response.result {

      case .success(let value):
          print(value)
      case .failure(let error):
          print(error)
     }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work. Also, you need to set `allow arbitary load` to `yes` (`App Transport Security Settings` in `info.plist`) if you want to allow requests over HTTP protocol.

This is NOT recommended, but it's fine for development.

Comment: It seems ok, but how can i return a variable that i declare in the loop ? When i declare it in an other place, i have thread errors

Comment: I usually declare a class property. ```var results: JSON = []``` and below  I just add ```self.results = JSON(value)``` in ```.success(let value)``` case, so I can later use it. But this requires ```SwiftyJSON```.

Comment: But, because it is asynchronous, i can't store the variable because the request ends after the print i do. How would you set your semaphores ? Or something else maybe ?